# find longest consequence of numbers so adjacents are factors or multiples

Tags: python, recursion, processing-efficiency

There is a puzzle to find the longest chain of numbers from 1 to 100 so that each next number should be multiple or factor for previous one. Each number can be taken once. I'm bad at programming but it was very interesting for me and I spent few hours with it.
I'm wondering how this my code could be made more effective. Now it can solve for only around 20 numbers in reasonable time.
I suppose a lot of time is spent for 2 list copy operations and .pop(i) operation. Thank you.
p.s. This is not homework.

> Output for numbers=10 is [4, 8, 1, 5, 10, 2, 6, 3, 9]

```
qty = 100
max_length = 0
max = []

def main():
    numbers = list(range(1, qty + 1))
    solve([], numbers, 0)
    print(max)

def check_result(result):
    global qty, max_length, max
    if len(result) > max_length:
        max = result
        max_length = len(result)   

def solve(bufer, left, index):
    if index == qty:
        check_result(bufer)

    for i in range(len(left)):
        left_c = left.copy()
        bufer_c = bufer.copy()
        next = left_c.pop(i)

        if index == 0 or next % bufer_c[index - 1] == 0 or bufer_c[index - 1] % next == 0:
            bufer_c.append(next)
            solve(bufer_c, left_c, index + 1)
        else:
            check_result(bufer_c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yeah, you're doing a lot of copying of lists.  That's gotta be killing your times.  I'm not sure if I understand exactly what the output should be.  It would be helpful if you could provide expected output.

Comment: @CryptoFool. Added output for 10 numbers

Comment: To do this right I'm guessing would involve graph theory.  I'm thinking that you'd build a graph where pairs of numbers where one is a factor of the other would be connected with an edge. Once you'd built the graph, you would then look for the longest path through the graph without hitting the same node twice.  That's probably too much for you.  It would be too much for me without doing some studying.  But I think that's the way to approach this problem in an optimized way.  Otherwise, the brute-force way you're doing is ok.  You just need to limit slow ops, like copying lists.

Comment: @CryptoFool thank you, haven't thought of it. Would be interesting to research graphs with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

No deep insights here, just a few optimizations - it gets up to n = 35 in about a minute. The current method is essentially already a graph search, so finding the [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) efficiently is going to be difficult/impossible.

```
qty=35
max_length = 0
max = []
nr = 0

# precompute factors
factors = [[q for q in range(2, p) if p % q == 0] for p in range(1, qty+1)]

def main():
    numbers = list(range(1, qty + 1))
    left = [True] * qty
    left[0] = False
    solve([1], left, 1)
    print(max)

def check_result(result):
    global qty, max_length, max, nr
    if len(result) > max_length:
        nr += 1
        max = result.copy()
        max_length = len(result)   

def solve(bufer, left, index):
    global max
    if index > max_length:
        check_result(bufer)

    # do the multiples first 
    mult = bufer[index-1]*2
    while mult <= qty:
        if left[mult-1]:
            left[mult-1] = False
            bufer.append(mult)
            solve(bufer, left, index+1)
            bufer.pop()
            left[mult-1] = True
        mult += bufer[index-1]
    
    # then the factors
    for factor in factors[bufer[index-1] - 1]:
        if left[factor-1]:
            left[factor-1] = False
            bufer.append(factor)
            solve(bufer, left, index+1)
            bufer.pop()
            left[factor-1] = True
```

The optimizations are to only check the multiples and factors of the previous element and avoid copying lists. The list of numbers left is now a lookup table. I also fixed the starting element to be 1 - once the chain to the 'right' of 1 has been found, you can find the chain to the 'left' using the remaining numbers (I didn't implement this).

Comment: thanks! I will look at it thoroughly. But at first glance it outputs [1, 3, 6, 2, 4] for qty=6, while it should output [3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5]

Comment: Yes I fixed the first item to be 1, the full chain is found by continuing the process to the left using the remaining numbers. Although on second thought, perhaps this could effect the optimality of the overall solution.

Comment: It doesn't find best solution if it starts not form 1:
For n=20 it should be [7, 14, 2, 8, 16, 4, 12, 6, 18, 9, 3, 15, 5, 10, 20, 1, 19].

Comment: But it finds [1, 7, 14, 2, 8, 16, 4, 12, 6, 18, 9, 3, 15, 5, 10, 20], which is easily made into [19, 1, 7, 14, 2, 8, 16, 4, 12, 6, 18, 9, 3, 15, 5, 10, 20] with the method I describe (since any number can be left/right of 1). Anyway this was just an optimization to reduce the size of the search space by a factor of `N`, it could be suboptimal in general like I said.